# How to import grouped products in magento?

Tags: magento

I have created a Grouped Product as below

```
Wallpaper
  -- Wallpaper 12  X 12
  -- Wallpaper 16 X 16
  -- Wallpaper 18 X 18
```

It work fine and easy to manage if there is few products. But in my store i would have more than 20 different sizes for each product and creating and adding simple product under "Associated Products" in the Grouped product is time consuming.

is there any way to directly upload the grouped products into Magento? do i have to create a special Import profile for this? if so how?

Please give me a hand on this.

Thanks,
Balan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 modules for import like: Amartinez_CustomImportExport and Magmi. They should solve your problem. If they don't do it, then you should write your own module for importing such products, which is not so difficult.

Comment: I've used both and generally prefer the Amartinez module, not as easy to use, but I found it faster and more stable than magmi.

Comment: Yeah, Amartinez module is more stable because it uses Magento's API, not database.

Answer (score 0):

please use the following code to import programmatically.
https://www.pearlbells.co.uk/import-grouped-products-magento/

```
function setGroupedProducts( $product, $simpleProdSkus ) {

try {

    $grpProducts = array();
    $simpleProductSkus = explode(',',$simpleProdSkus);
    $i = 0;

    foreach ($simpleProductSkus as $simpleProdSku) {

        $simple_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $simpleProdSku);

        if (is_object($simple_product)) {

            $grpProducts[$i++] = $simple_product->getId();

        }
    }

    $products_links = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_link_api');

    foreach($grpProducts as $id) {
        $products_links->assign ("grouped",$product->getId(),$id);
    }

    return $product;
} 
catch (Exception $ex) {
    Mage::log($ex->getMessage(),null,'grp.log');
}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually MAGMI works for this task like a charm. Although it uses direct SQL queries, it's quite stable (I'd say it's 99% stable for most of tasks if correctly used).

Check out [this cheat sheet with an example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AgOC3MxA5YaLdFFwTk9uY2RQbmthQmZZdmVYZ3FUOEE&usp=drive_web#gid=6) for getting quick reference on how to import your grouped/simple connection. In 2 words, it's very easy with MAGMI, just need to define a column **grouped_skus** having comma-separated list of attached simple products. That's all. Ah, also don't forget to include column "type" = grouped if you are in "create" mode.

```
type    grouped_skus                                    
grouped CHOCKOLATE-BAR,CHOCKOLATE-MILK,CHOCKOLATE-CAKE
```

Comment: Why downvoting? Didn't my reply help anyone? I'm sure it did :-)